# Loop through timestamps SQL

Tags: mysql, r, timestamp

I was wondering if anyone could help me out. I got a tiny R script querying a MySQL table where jobs are submitted and logged and for this question only 3 columns matter:

```
| insertTimeStamp     | startTimeStamp      | finishedTimeStamp   |
| 2021-01-12 15:31:43 | 2021-01-12 15:31:59 | 2021-01-12 15:37:37 | 
| 2021-01-12 15:31:43 | 2021-01-12 15:31:59 | 2021-01-12 15:37:11 | 
| 2021-01-12 15:31:43 | 2021-01-12 15:31:59 | 2021-01-12 15:37:15 | 
| 2021-01-12 15:31:43 | 2021-01-12 15:31:59 | 2021-01-12 15:36:56 | 
| 2021-01-12 15:31:43 | 2021-01-12 15:31:59 | 2021-01-12 15:37:04 | 
| 2021-01-12 15:31:43 | 2021-01-12 15:31:59 | 2021-01-12 15:36:50 | 
| 2021-01-12 15:31:43 | 2021-01-12 15:31:59 | 2021-01-12 15:39:14 | 
| 2021-01-12 15:31:43 | 2021-01-12 15:31:59 | 2021-01-12 15:43:13 | 
| 2021-01-12 15:31:43 | 2021-01-12 15:31:59 | 2021-01-12 15:36:40 | 
| 2021-01-12 15:31:43 | 2021-01-12 15:31:59 | 2021-01-12 15:36:48 | 
| 2021-01-12 15:31:43 | 2021-01-12 15:31:59 | 2021-01-12 15:36:04 | 
| 2021-01-12 15:31:43 | 2021-01-12 15:31:59 | 2021-01-12 15:37:08 | 
| 2021-01-12 15:31:43 | 2021-01-12 15:31:59 | 2021-01-12 15:36:12 | 
| 2021-01-12 15:31:43 | 2021-01-12 15:31:59 | 2021-01-12 15:37:48 | 
| 2021-01-12 15:31:43 | 2021-01-12 15:31:59 | 2021-01-12 15:37:53 | 
| 2021-01-12 15:31:43 | 2021-01-12 15:31:59 | 2021-01-12 15:40:00 | 
| 2021-01-12 15:31:43 | 2021-01-12 15:31:59 | 2021-01-12 15:36:57 | 
| 2021-01-12 15:31:43 | 2021-01-12 15:31:59 | 2021-01-12 15:37:10 | 
| 2021-01-12 15:31:43 | 2021-01-12 15:31:59 | 2021-01-12 15:36:34 | 
| 2021-01-12 15:31:43 | 2021-01-12 15:31:59 | 2021-01-12 15:37:32 | 
| 2021-01-12 15:31:43 | 2021-01-12 15:31:59 | 2021-01-12 15:37:03 | 
| 2021-01-12 15:31:43 | 2021-01-12 15:31:59 | 2021-01-12 15:37:21 | 
| 2021-01-12 15:31:43 | 2021-01-12 15:31:59 | 2021-01-12 15:38:33 | 
| 2021-01-12 15:31:43 | 2021-01-12 15:31:59 | 2021-01-12 15:37:36 | 
| 2021-01-12 15:31:43 | 2021-01-12 15:31:59 | 2021-01-12 15:36:48 | 
| 2021-01-12 15:31:43 | 2021-01-12 15:31:59 | 2021-01-12 15:36:26 | 
| 2021-01-12 15:31:43 | 2021-01-12 15:31:59 | 2021-01-12 15:36:28 | 
| 2021-01-12 15:31:43 | 2021-01-12 15:31:59 | 2021-01-12 15:37:06 | 
| 2021-01-12 15:31:43 | 2021-01-12 15:31:59 | 2021-01-12 15:33:51 | 
| 2021-01-12 15:31:43 | 2021-01-12 15:31:59 | 2021-01-12 15:38:41 | 
| 2021-01-12 15:31:43 | 2021-01-12 15:31:59 | 2021-01-12 15:37:52 | 
| 2021-01-12 15:31:43 | 2021-01-12 15:31:59 | 2021-01-12 15:37:20 | 
| 2021-01-12 15:31:43 | 2021-01-12 15:31:59 | 2021-01-12 15:36:32 | 
| 2021-01-12 15:31:43 | 2021-01-12 15:31:59 | 2021-01-12 15:36:37 | 
| 2021-01-12 15:31:43 | 2021-01-12 15:31:59 | 2021-01-12 15:38:40 | 

(35 rows, 35 jobs in this timeframe)
```

A job can be picked up immediately or queued for some time. So I made an R script that makes a graph of this data:
[image: Jobs per timestamp]

As you can see in the plot. The x-axis has a tick of 1 minute, and every job is queued (and started) at around 15:32:00.
The data.table that is provided for this plot (before melting) looks like this:

```
   currentTimeStamp Queued Started Finished
2021-01-12 15:31:00      0       0        0
2021-01-12 15:32:00     35      35        0
2021-01-12 15:33:00      0      35        0
2021-01-12 15:34:00      0      34        1
2021-01-12 15:35:00      0      34        1
2021-01-12 15:36:00      0      34        1
2021-01-12 15:37:00      0      22       14
2021-01-12 15:38:00      0       6       29
2021-01-12 15:39:00      0       3       32
2021-01-12 15:40:00      0       2       34
2021-01-12 15:41:00      0       1       34
```

**My goal**

I would like to generate this (or similar) table through a MySQL query. It should loop through a given time frame (`WHERE insertTimeStamp BETWEEN '2020-01-12 15:30:00' AND '2020-01-12 15:41:00'`) with a counting iteration every 5 minutes, which gives the count of how many jobs are queued (not yet started or finished), started (but not finished) or finished.

Comment: If all jobs start at 32, how come they also start at 33?

Comment: there is no godd way for mysql first without mysql 8 you have ahell of a time to get all minutes coverd, but even then you need still a FULL OUTER Join whuich mysql doesn't support. Finally your cpunt doesn't makemuch sense for the data provided

Comment: @Strawberry, they start at 32, but are not (yet) finished at 33, so they remain classified as started

Comment: @nbk thank you for your answer and time! I'll try a different way then

Comment: @TrainedMusician if you want to see how that in mysql looks like(without the missing minutes see https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5b092722e5f24600d017033b2af362cc